# Não consigo criar um projeto com create-react-app

Tags: javascript, react, npm

Não consigo mais criar aplicativos com o create-react-app, já criei alguns projetos usando o create-react-app, porém agora parou de funcionar.

Executo o seguinte comando para criar uma aplicação:

```
> npx create-react-app my-app
```

```
npx: installed 98 in 18.156s

Creating a new React app in C:\Workspace\react\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 13 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-scripts@3.4.1
└─ react@16.13.1
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@7.9.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.9.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.9.6
├─ @babel/preset-typescript@7.9.0
├─ babel-preset-react-app@9.1.2
├─ cra-template@1.0.3
├─ eslint-config-react-app@5.2.1
├─ react-dev-utils@10.2.1
├─ react-dom@16.13.1
├─ react-error-overlay@6.0.7
├─ react-scripts@3.4.1
├─ react@16.13.1
└─ scheduler@0.19.1
Done in 62.02s.
```

O processo simplesmente para de executar após instalar as dependencias, as pastas src e public não são criadas.

Alguém pode me dar alguma dica de como resolver isso ou onde posso encontrar mais logs do problema?

Suspeito que seja algo relacionado ao git, já que o próximo passo depois da instalação de dependencias é a incialização do repositório git.

Grato,
V. Goulart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geralmente problemas com o `create-react-app` ocorrem quando você possui uma versão instalada na sua máquina e então está tentando executar o comando com uma versão antiga, conforme [documentação](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) (tradução livre):

> Se você já instalou o `create-react-app` globalmente via `npm install
>   -g create-react-app`, recomendamos desinstalar o pacote usando o `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` para garantir que o `npx` sempre use a
>   versão mais recente.

O comando equivalente no `yarn` é `yarn global remove create-react-app`.

Caso o problema persista após a remoção do pacote, encontrei uma alternativa [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59188624/8839059) do SOen. Use o comando `which create-react-app` (Linux / Mac) ou `where create-react-app` (Windows) e, caso retorne um caminho para o diretório do `create-react-app`, basta remover esse diretório e tentar novamente.

Comment: Removi a pasta e funcionou, muito obrigado!