# create-react-app criando apenas node module e package.json

Tags: javascript, react, npm

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com um problema ao tentar criar uma aplicação com React. Ao usar o comando `npx create-react-app` apenas é criado o `node_modules` e o `package.json` e nada mais da template que deveria vir. Já tentei usar `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` caso o problema fosse que tinha instalado global mas o error continua a acontecer.

Já tinha criado outras aplicações com React antes normalmente mas agora toda vez que tento tenho esse problema.

Como posso corrigir esse erro e fazer com que funcione normalmente?

Agradeço desde já

Comment: Veja se isso resolve o seu problema: [Não consigo criar um projeto com create-react-app](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/453574/100416)

Comment: Tentei já seguir esses passos mas o erro continua acontecendo